# UIview starting center is deceptively incorrect. (False Visual)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, uipangesturerecognizer

Video Explanation: 
[image: Example]

I have a UIView that you can drag to the center of another view to perform an action. This view is supposed to have a leading constraint from the center view + 24.

Its starting center X value I print on larger iphones (iphone 8) is ~324.

On iphone 5s and some other smaller phones, the view appears to be placed at the correct location but once I move the view it is snaps back to an incorrect position. The .ended PanGesture will have it snap to its starting center X value.

I print its starting value at 324 but once I move it it snaps to 324 which is to the right off screen.

What is causing this? Why does it appear to be in a correct place at start?

Pangesture for Checkbutton below:

```
@objc func checkButtonWasDragged(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: checkButton)
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        checkButton.center = CGPoint(x: checkButton.center.x + translation.x, y: checkButton.center.y)
        print(checkButton.center.x)
        distanceCounter += translation.x
        if distanceCounter > 0 {
            distanceCounter = 0
        }
        if checkButton.center.x > startingPointCheckBtn {
            checkButton.center.x = startingPointCheckBtn
        } else if checkButton.center.x < largeCircle.center.x && distanceCounter < checkBtnDistance{
            checkButton.center.x = largeCircle.center.x
            distanceCounter = checkBtnDistance
        } else {
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        }
        // hide the buttons after we drag over them
        if distanceCounter < -60.0 && !rightCirclesHidden {
            for circle in rightCircles {
                circle.layer.removeAllAnimations()
                circle.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
            }
            rightCirclesHidden = true
        } else if distanceCounter > -60.0 && rightCirclesHidden {
            for i in 0..<leftCircles.count {
                leftCircles[i].layer.removeAllAnimations()
                //rightCircles[i].backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
                rightCircles[i].backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
                leftCircles[i].backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            }
            startAnimatingCircles()
            rightCirclesHidden = false
        }
    } else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        if largeCircle.center.x - checkButton.center.x >= -35.0 {
            checkButton.center = largeCircle.center
            self.loadSignUpPage()
        } else {
            checkButton.center.x = startingPointCheckBtn
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            print(startingPointCheckBtn)
            if rightCirclesHidden {
                for i in 0..<leftCircles.count {
                    leftCircles[i].layer.removeAllAnimations()
                    //rightCircles[i].backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
                    rightCircles[i].backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
                    leftCircles[i].backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
                }
                startAnimatingCircles()
                rightCirclesHidden = false
            }
        }
        distanceCounter = 0
    }
}
```

Constraints on the greenCheck:
[image: Check Constraints]

viewDidLoad() is calling:

```
setUpCheckButton()
```

setUpCheckButton code:

```
    func setUpCheckButton() {
    startingPointCheckBtn = checkButton.center.x
    print("check circle center: " + "\(startingPointCheckBtn)")
    checkBtnDistance = largeCircle.center.x - startingPointCheckBtn
    let checkGestureDrag = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AdViewPageVC.checkButtonWasDragged(_:)))
    checkButton.addGestureRecognizer(checkGestureDrag)
}
```

Comment: Show the code please for the panGesture and te constraints for the views.

Comment: Updated question with more info

Comment: Woah that's a lot of checks. But seeing what you need. It should just work if you stored the starting position of `checkButton` in `startingPointCheckButton`. Check if the starting position is indeed being stored in that variable. Also i suggest you use the autolayout constraints for animation.

Comment: Yes it is quite a few to make sure I get it to behave as it should. The odd this is I grab the starting checkButton X at viewDidLoad. It is still a value way off the screen.

Comment: Also use `UIView.animate` to ease in your checkMark landing back the original position.

Comment: I actually like that idea thank you. Its gonna fatten up that method though ha.

Comment: Please show that code in `viewDidAppear`. I think you might have used frame instead of bounds or something.

Comment: Okay, it was in view did Load. Placing in now

Comment: All up and there.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be just 24 points from the largeCircle. The leading anchor.

Comment: It is because the imageView is larger than what it appears. The actual check button width is 112.5 and 107 with the propoartional sizes

Comment: The check button had room around it when it was given to me by the person who sliced the images etc

Comment: Can you join back in chat?

Comment: Yes i am able to join

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176848/discussion-between-rakesha-shastri-and-a-petrizza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting it in `viewDidLoad` you should set it in `viewDidAppear` so that you get the actual value when the checkMark is on screen. Also change your gesture ended block to this.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.70, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
      self.checkButton.center.x = self.startingPointCheckBtn
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```